# Rails has_many error - Couldn't find ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop

I have a Comment and Reply.
comment has_many replies

routes.rb

```
resources :comments do
  resources :replies
end
```

When I open comments/index and then select comments/show I print information about all the replies that are related to that comment.

```
<% @comment.replies.each do |reply| %>
```

I can also create another reply. All this works properly.

The problem comes when I decide to edit one of those replies.

```
<%=  link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_reply_path(@comment.replies,reply) %>
```

The strange thing is that if there is a comment with an ID the same as the ID of the reply that I want to modify, the edit is working properly. It is not even necessary the particular reply that I want to modify to belongs to that comment. But in case I want to edit reply with ID for example 66, but there is not a comment with id 66, I get an error:

```
Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=65
<%=form_with(model: @reply, url: [Comment.find(params[:id]), @reply]) do |form| %>
```

This is replies/_form.html.erb which apparently works as an edit form as well. In this case the reply.id is 65 and it is looking for a comment with the same ID which is not present.

Comment: can you add output of `rake routes` to your question?

Comment: @xeon131  yes I will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try?

```
<%=  link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_reply_path(reply) %>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This just let me get into the edit link. Now I Have another problem when I click on update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line of code.

`<%=  link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_reply_path(@comment.replies,reply) %>`

The `edit_comment_reply_path` method takes `@comment` as its first argument.

The correct code should be

```
<%=  link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_reply_path(@comment, reply) %>
```

Provided that you have assigned `@comment` in your controller `edit` action.

```
def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
end
```

Or

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:create, :edit]
```

The point is you must set the `@comment` in the correct action for the view.

The `form_for` is incorrect. You can passing in `params[:id]` which is the `id` of `@reply`.

```
<%= form_with(model: @reply, url: comment_reply_path(@comment, @reply)) do |form| %>
```

Comment: I've just added it @jackii

Comment: If I add @comment to before_action :set_comment I get another error param is missing or the value is empty: reply The line that causes error is the reply_params code

Comment: If he is passing the `@comment` to the `edit` method. no need to add `set_comment` method to before create actions. right?

Comment: @John please try out my answer, change the form_for

Comment: @jackii when I use form_with I have undefined method `replies_path' RubyMine's suggestion says Can't find declaration for field @reply.

Comment: The url should be  comment_reply_path(@comment, @reply)

Comment: This answer has most of the fixes (combined with the post above that pointed you're using `post_id` rather than `comment_id`). However, do you need to specify the url in the form? Seems like it might run into issues if you're trying to use the form for both new and edit. The Rail's form should infer the url based on the record passed to the model argument.

Comment: @inveterateliterate What are you suggesting ?Do you think I should try create another form for edit. I am still not sure how to write form_for or form_with that is going to work

Comment: I am suggesting dropping the `url` argument from your `form_with` method: `<%= form_with(model: @reply) do |form| %> `. Rails should be able to figure out the correct method and url for the form based on whether `@reply` is a new or persisted record: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Answer (score 0):

What do your controllers look like? Also, you shouldn't be able to access replies that do not belong to your comment. Look at using proper scoping and authorization. I would guess the only reason it works is luck; because you do have a comment_id that matches the reply_id, the call does not fail.

Comment: @MichaelJamati I will edit my post and will add replies controller

Answer (score 0):

Ok, can you also post your comments controller. 
A few points: 
Make use of authorizations in your relevant functions (suggestion; assuming you're using policies)

```
def edit
  authorize @reply
end
```

If you plan on passing in the comment id, you should also set_comment (not just in create). That way you can also make sure the reply edit is not executed using a comment that does not belong to your user (or some other unwanted behaviours).

And also, you question talks about looking for Id 66, but the error mentions ID 65. Is that just a typo?

Comment: My explanation was just an example. When I added set_comment in edit I've got another error @MichaelJamati

Answer (score 0):

In your `RepliesController` change the set comment method to

```
 def set_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(reply_params[:comment_id])
  end
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=):
  
app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:80:in `set_comment'
But I think post_id and comment_id are duplicating instances, so they have the same value @xeon131

Comment: ohh ok, Can you post your scheme?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Can you put a `binding.pry` in your edit action and post the `params`? or post the debug output (log from where your server(rails s) is running)

Comment: Also, How is `post_id` getting data? Do you also have a `posts` tables?

Comment: comments/_form.html.erb  <%= form.hidden_field(:post_id, :value => params[:id]) %> this is how I create reply 
"<%= link_to 'Reply', new_comment_reply_path(/@comment, :id => /@comment.id, :title =>/@comment.title) %>" The /@ are because i cant use multiple @ in a comment

Comment: Regardless of whether `post_id` and `comment_id` somehow got duplicated and have the same value, it is strongly recommended that you maintain consistency in your naming conventions. If you are no longer using posts, and replies simply belong to comments, then just stick with referring to `comment_id` as applicable. It will make tracking the records and debugging easier.

Comment: Additionally, the rails path helpers take records as arguments, i.e., just `new_comment_reply_path(@comment)` (assuming `@comment` is defined). What are you trying to send through with that extra information?