# Rails has_many update is not happening wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, oop

I don't receive any error after trying to update a reply that belongs to a post. But after the update nothing is happening - the values are not changed.

This is the form that I am using

```
form_with(model: @reply, url: [Comment.find(params[:id]), @reply]) do |form|
```

The parameters passed to the page. The naming is not very convenient but the id is the comment.id and the comment_id is the reply id. And I am not sure at what point did these two got swapped

```
Parameters: {"comment_id"=>"75", "id"=>"60"}
```

What I do notice is that the link seems to be wrong:

```
http://localhost:3000/comments/75/replies/60/edit
```

As I said the comment id is 60 and the reply id is 75, so I am assuming that it should look like:

```
http://localhost:3000/comments/60/replies/75/edit
```

There are no errors in the console and when I run rails c Reply.last there are no modifications at all + the updated_at hasn't been changed.

Reply controller - update

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @reply.update(reply_params)
      format.html {redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Reply was successfully updated.'}
      format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @reply}
    else
      format.html {render :edit}
      format.json {render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
    end
  end
end
```

What I also observed is if I add line of code inside the update if statement all the replies of the desired comment will be updated

```
 @comment.replies.update(reply_params)
```

Comment: I would take another look at all of the answers and comments on your previous question, as I see similar issues here. I also encourage you to review the Rails guides on forms and controllers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487049/rails-has-many-error-couldnt-find-id/47487211?noredirect=1#comment81932286_47487211

Comment: @inveterateliterate In fact your suggestion gives me an error, but I replaced it with "form_for([Comment.find(params[:id]), @reply]) do |form|" and I still have that issue. What would you say about the last bit of this question with updating all the instances ?

Comment: What if you just try `form_for(@reply) do |form|` ?
To the last bit the reason it is updating all of the replies is because you are first calling all of the comment's replies: `@comment.replies`. You really just want to update the 1 reply, like you have above: `@reply.update(reply_params)`.

Comment: @inveterateliterate when I use form_for reply do form I receive undefined method `replies_path'. Yes but reply.update(reply_params) is not working.